# How can I update the font size and background color of my Tooltip and make its icon smaller?

Tags: html, css, angular, tooltip

I have tried for hours to get this to work trying multiple solved stack solutions and none have worked.

I am assuming I am either missing something or I have my divs/spans incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Currently my text is very small and bg color is grey and slightly transparent.

Also if it is possible to make the "info" icon smaller that would be great as well. Thank you!

```css
  .mainContainer {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
  }
  
    .info {
    display: flex;
  }

  .info .span {
    align-self: center;
  }

  .info-button{
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    top:-10px;
  }
```

```html
      <div class="mainContainer">
        <h3>Main Title</h3>
        <div class="info">
          <h5>Title</h5><span class="info-span">
            <button mat-icon-button class="info-button" #tooltip="matTooltip" matTooltip="Tooltip Text">
            <mat-icon color="basic" >info</mat-icon>
            </button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

You can set `!important`  if not working.

Hope useful

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly thank you. I thought ng-deep was deprecated so I did not even think to try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **popper js** to integrate and style  tooltips  it's easy and simple :
this is a quick exemple from the documentation :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Popper example</title>

<style>
#tooltip {
background-color: #333;
color: white;
padding: 5px 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 13px;
}
</style>

<button id="button" aria-describedby="tooltip">I'm a button</button>
<div id="tooltip" role="tooltip">I'm a tooltip</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script>
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
const tooltip = document.querySelector('#tooltip');

// Pass the button, the tooltip, and some options, and Popper will do the
// magic positioning for you:
Popper.createPopper(button, tooltip, {
placement: 'right',
});
</script>
```

or visit the official website  to learn about popper js :[Tutorial](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/tutorial/)